# Keycloak with Spring boot - How to apply resource scopes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak 7.0.1 with Spring Boot 1.5.16.RELEASE securing endpoint by specifying resources, role based polices and permissions - and that's works as expected.

The tricky things is to secure only POST and allow GET requests to one some particular URIs. What have I done in application.yml:

```
policy-enforcer-config:
  enforcement-mode: ENFORCING
  paths[0]:
    name: all
    path: /*
  paths[1]:
    name: test post
  path: /my/url
    methods[0]:
      method: GET
      scopes[0]: view
    methods[1]:
      method: POST
      scopes[0]: edit
```

In keyclaok I've created `edit` and `view` scopes, `/my/url` resource, policy with role and negative decision (if user has that role - deny access), permission contains resource, scope and policy. Evaluation works as expected, but my spring application always receive 403 error.

Could you provide me with an example of resource scope usage or advice what else shout be done to make that working?

Comment: `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` are you using this annotation with spring security?

Comment: No, just ant matchers

Answer (score 3):

Could be multiple problems, but first of all, check your SecurityConfig.

This is what we have in place:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KeycloakSpringBootProperties.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    bla-bla..

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/**")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**")
            // allow anonymous resource requests
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    "/",
                    "/*.html",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js",
                    "/actuator/**"

            )
    ;
}


    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
            .csrf().disable()

            .exceptionHandling()
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                    getRestAuthenticationEntryPoint(),
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")
            )
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()

            // don't create session
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()

            .authorizeRequests()

            // system state endpoint
            .antMatchers("/ping").permitAll()

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/whatever/you/need/to/open/to/public/one", "/whatever/you/need/to/open/to/public/two").permitAll()


            // User authentication actions
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**/*.css").permitAll()

            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    ;

    http
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    ;

    // disable page caching
    http
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
            .cacheControl();

}
```

If you want to restrict REST API endpoints with role, add @PreAuthorize("hasRole('your.role.from.keycloak')") for your controller method

Comment: Thx, that's implemented and working. Can't leverage only POST and GET segregation